# find limit of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

I have to show continuity at $(0,0)$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x^2) + \sin(y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

I tried to find the limit using polar coordinates

$ \frac{\sin(r^2\cos^2 α) + \sin(r^2\sin^2 α)}{r} $

but it's still $\frac00$

Comment: Now multiply and divide each of those sines by what they have inside and use that $\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\sin(a)}{a}=1$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

$|f(x,y)| \leq \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}} \to 0$ because $|\sin \, t| \leq |t|$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}T&:=\frac{\sin \ x^2+\sin\ y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
 \\&=\frac{\sin \ x^2 }{x^2}\frac{x^2}{
 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} +
 \frac{\sin\ y^2}{y^2}\frac{y^2}{
 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\&\leq \frac{\sin \ x^2 }{x^2}\frac{x^2 +y^2}{
 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} +
 \frac{\sin\ y^2}{y^2}\frac{x^2+y^2}{
 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \rightarrow 0 \end{align*}

When $x,\ y\rightarrow 0$, then $T\geq 0$ so that $T$ has a limit
$0$